# BuildError: Could not build url for endpoint 'Edit.edit'. Did you forget to specify values ['id']?

Tags: python, html, flask

How can i solve this error. i have tried everything but it isn't working.

Here is my flask code

```
    @Edit.route('/edit/<int:id>', methods = ['POST' , 'GET'])
def edit(id):
    connection = create_connection()
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    # After connecting to the database, the following query has been made so that the admin can delete a user data
    sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE userid = %s"
    values = (id)
    #executes a sql query on the database
    cursor.execute(sql, values)
```

Here is edit.html

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="{{ url_for('Edit.edit') }}" method="post" id = "prim_skills_form">
```

Here is index.html

```
<a href="/edit/{{row.userid}}" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs">Edit</a>
```

My expectation is that when I click the edit button on the index page, the page related to the user I clicked will open. I may have asked incompletely, you can leave a comment for additional information.

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed return statement. 
So I think your code should look something like this:
**Flask code:**

```
@Edit.route('/edit/<int:id>', methods = ['POST' , 'GET'])
def edit(id):
    connection = create_connection()
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    # After connecting to the database, the following query has been made so that the admin can delete a user data
    sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE userid = %s"
    values = (id,)
    #executes a sql query on the database
    cursor.execute(sql, args=values)
    return render_template('edit.html')
```

**edit.html**:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="" method="post" id = "prim_skills_form">
```

**index.html**:

```
<a href="{{url_for('Edit.edit', id=row.userid)}}" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs">Edit</a>
```